# Service hook subscription using javascript

Tags: javascript, azure-devops, webhooks

I want to create a service hook subscription for team projects on time of creation. I have tried REST API method, but it needs additional authentication even though I signed in VSTS.

Can anyone please help me?

I have tried REST API:

```
{ 
    "publisherId": "tfs",
    "eventType": " workitem.created",
    "resourceVersion": "1.0",
    "consumerId": "webHooks",
    "consumerActionId": "httpRequest",
    "publisherInputs": { 
        “areaPath”: “MyProject”, 

        "projectId": "my project id"
    }, 
    "consumerInputs": { "url": "my azure url" }, 
}
```

Comment: There is a problem with `“` in `“areaPath”: “MyProject”,`. It should be `"areaPath": "MyProject",` instead or not?

Comment: I didn't see any issue with the body content you provide, what issue do you have with it?

Answer (score 0):

To use Rest API, you need to use [OAuth2.0](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/get-started/auth/oauth) or enable "Alternate authentication credentials" from "My Profile\Security\Alternate authentication credentials". And when you use "Post" method to create a subscription, please also remember to include "Content-Type: application/json" in the header.